# Cursor to update values in certain fashion

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a table like this:

```
ID  Dates      Count
1   03-02-2014  2
2   04-02-2014  1
3   05-02-2014  NULL
4   06-02-2014  1
5   07-02-2014  3
6   08-02-2014  NULL
7   09-02-2014  2
8   10-02-2014  NULL
9   11-02-2014  1
10  12-02-2014  3
11  13-02-2014  NULL
12  14-02-2014  1
```

I have an INT variable having some value such as @XCount = 15.

My requirement is to update the count column with (@XCount - Count) such as the result of previous record will be subtracted by the Count value in the next record.

Result:

```
ID  Dates        Count  
1   03-02-2014  13  (15-2)
2   04-02-2014  12  (13-1)
3   05-02-2014  12  (12-0)
4   06-02-2014  11  (12-1)
5   07-02-2014  8   (11-3)
6   08-02-2014  8   (8-0)
7   09-02-2014  6   (8-2)
8   10-02-2014  6   (6-0)
9   11-02-2014  5   (6-1)
10  12-02-2014  2   (5-3)
11  13-02-2014  2   (2-0)
12  14-02-2014  1   (2-1)
```

I'm reluctant to use cursors as a solution. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @XCount INT = 15

;WITH Vals AS(
  SELECT ID, Dates, [Count] OriginalCount, @XCount - ISNULL([COUNT],0) NewCount
  FROM Table1
  WHERE ID = 1  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ID, t.Dates, t.[Count], v.NewCount - ISNULL(t.[Count],0)
  FROM Table1 t INNER JOIN Vals v ON t.ID = v.ID + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM Vals
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26ef2/9)

Do note thought that this is a recursive query, and that sometimes (until the tech allows for it, such as SQL SERVER 2012 `LAG` or `Running totals`) old does work.